# I am trying to search List company name in sheets using Google search

Tags: google-sheets

I used the formula

```
=IMPORTXML("https://www.google.com/search?q=daikin","//span[2]")
```

For example Daikin
it returned
[image]

But the result always shows in one column and different rows
How to make it into different columns  like city , website

Thanks for your support

Comment: share a copy / sample of your sheet with an example of the desired output

Comment: [link](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1pCAFsR1hHOaXlQERPqRu6HOgwUk_rrzUr_VGYyCQcQo/edit#gid=0)_italic_**bold**'code'
@player0